# Symfony2: Passing options to buildForm

Tags: php, symfony

So I'm pretty new to Symfony and I'm trying to have the controller build slightly different forms based on controller actions. Right now, I have this

```
//in Controller

public function addLocationEntryAction(Request $request)
{
    $entry = new Entry();
    $form = $this->get('form.factory')->create(new EntryType('addLocation'), $entry);

    return $this->render('OOTNBlogBundle:Blog:addEntry.html.twig', array(
        'form' => $form->createView()
    ));
}

public function addArticleEntryAction(Request $request)
{
    $entry = new Entry();
    $form = $this->get('form.factory')->create(new EntryType('addArticle'), $entry);

    return $this->render('OOTNBlogBundle:Blog:addEntry.html.twig', array(
        'form' => $form->createView()
    ));
}
```

And

```
//in EntryType

public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{

    $builder
        ->add('title',      'text')
        ->add('continent',  'text', array('required' => false))
        ->add('country',    'text', array('required' => false))
        ->add('category',   'text', array('required' => false))
        ->add('author',     'hidden')
        ->add('type',       'hidden')
        ->add('text',       'textarea')
        ->add('post',       'submit')
    ;
}
```

I'd like to pass an option from the controller in `buildForm`, so that I can do something like this:

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options, $option)
{
    $builder
        ->add('title',      'text')
    ;

    if($option == 'addLocation')
    {
        $builder
            ->add('continent',  'text', array('required' => false))
            ->add('country',    'text', array('required' => false))
        ;
    }
    elseif($option == 'addArticle')
    {
        $builder
            ->add('category',   'text', array('required' => false))
        ;
    }

    $builder
        ->add('author',     'hidden')
        ->add('type',       'hidden')
        ->add('text',       'textarea')
        ->add('post',       'submit')
    ;
}
```

How do I do this? I've checked out the Symfony doc and similar questions on here but nothing seems to be quite fitting for my case. I don't know.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

There is no need to create an additional param, just use `options` to pass custom data. In the following example, I made `age` attribute mandatory, you could have it optional or specify default value. Read more about `OptionsResolver` [here](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/options_resolver.html)

```
class ExampleType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        var_dump($options['age']);
    }

    public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setRequired(array(
            'age'
        ));

    }
}
```

Create:

```
$form = $this->get('form.factory')->create(new ExampleType(), $entry, array(
    'age' => 13
));
```

Comment: @b.b3rn4rd The best answer! Clear, simple, effective. In my case, also it works well

Comment: Note that `setDefaultOptions` is deprecated in favor of `configureOptions`. http://symfony.com/blog/new-in-symfony-2-7-form-and-validator-updates#deprecated-setdefaultoptions-in-favor-of-configureoptions